# How do to I push another viewController to the screen without having storyboard file ? I've tried the following code but nothing happens

Tags: swift

I tried doing this.

```
let vc = AdminInfo() as UIViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: Is `self.navigationController` nil? Do you have a `UINavigationController` at all? `AdminInfo()` has no Storyboard, all is done by code? Not even a xib?

Comment: the current self is a uiviewcontroller and AdminInfo is the same and I dont have a xib nor storyboard. But im tryna figure out how I can push another vc with storyboard

Comment: You need a UINavigationController to do a push. Else, you can present: `self.present(vc, animated: true)`

Comment: adminInfo is a UINavigationController but still won't push

Comment: the current self is a UINavigationController

Comment: Paste all code from both classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from Nib you can do it as following, 
in my case "MusicCategoryVC" is my ViewController.

```
   let nextvc = MusicCategoryVC(nibName: "MusicCategory", bundle: nil)
   navigationController?.pushViewController(nextvc, animated: true)
```

Comment: I didn't create Nib file for the class. Do I have to add that for it to work ? Because I don't have a storyboard file in my app

Comment: Im trying to present a tab bar controller from a navigation controller and my code is as follows:        let vc = TabController()
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil).        But when the tab bar controller is presented? The nav Bar is hidden. Why ?